# Strategy Pattern with versions - UML Design

Tags: php, architecture, uml, software-design, strategy-pattern

Currently I'm working on a webshop implementation in PHP (Aimeos, Laravel). I've arrived at the point where I need to create an import script. I started designing the UML class diagram and now I'm a bit stuck.

The import script that will be running will have a lot of possible implementations. There will be multiple different shops from which the export files will be used to run the import in my project. However, every one of these shops has multiple versions.

I came up with the idea of using a strategy pattern for implementing the import functionality.

This is what I have right now:
[image: UML Class Diagram of Import]

However, I want to implement multiple versions of each strategy. Since version 1.0 of XCart will have different columns and will require some different parsing strategies than for example version 1.5 of XCart.

My question is, what would be a good way of implementing such a structure? I thought of just making different strategies for the verions and naming my strategies: XCartStrategyOneZero and XCartStrategyOneFive. However, this feels totally wrong and unnatural to me. Do you guys have any suggestion. Maybe I should use a different design pattern? Or maybe the versions could somehow be implemented inside of the strategies. Or maybe I should make sub strategies for each version of each webshop that should be implemented.

Any suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: Are versions only historically reasoned or do they run concurrently?

Comment: The code will be ran once, but a user is able to upload multiple files. Where in a future version of the implementation, multiple types of web shop exports will be imported sequentially. So switching strategies will occur whilst the code is running. Also multiple versions of these web shops' exports are a possibility

Comment: Your approach doesn't look that bad. I'd probably add a version string in the interface so you can eventually react in importer.

Comment: I think I didn't explain it clear enough. Users have the possibility of uploading multiple files at once. These files can be a mix of export files from different shops with different versions. So one possibility is an upload with an export from xCart v1.0 and also from xCart 2.0. Both exports will be imported by my script. But both versions also have different strategies. So I'm still a bit stuck with the naming of the strategies. If I need to make two different strategies (one for each version) how would I name the classes (strategies) or maybe there is a better way for this use case.

Comment: Think about the factory pattern. You get the right class in return of some identifier (which you likely have to distinguish the export formats).

Comment: Combine your strategy with Abstract Factory.

Comment: I have chosen to use a strategy pattern. When the code is executed, I use Reflection to retrieve annotations in the available ImportStrategies. Then in respect to the annotation values (@minVersion and @maxVersion) a strategy is chosen and returned to be used in the import functionality. I use the php version_compare function to check whether the version stated in the strategies is equal to or between these two version. Because of this implementation I only have to add a strategy and a option to the select html element, from which the user can choose what import type he want to run.

Comment: I ran out of available characters in my last comment. I just want to thank you guys for helping me out. In a future version, I will have a look at the Abstract Factory pattern, to see if that would be a better way of implementing this. Thanks anyway!